# Json Object Store SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, json, sharedpreferences

Here I want to Json Object in SharedPreferences. I don't know it is the best way or not to store json object.

Here I want to store Json Object and whenver need call its Json object and fatch detail to store and remove detail.

here is my json format to store data.

Comments Contain All detail of my Comments on myPhoto/Myvideo
Mentions Contain All detail of my mention in comments 
Friends data contain my whole friend list follow/following.
Friends Updates and Friends Deleted will Contain if any friend removed

how I can store this kind of information in shared preference.
is it a right way?

```
 {
     "data": {
         "message": "List of comments",
         "comments": [
             {
                 "userId": 
                 "commentId": 
                 "name": 
                 "text": 
                "dateAdded": 
                "imageLink":
            }
    ],
    "addPosition": "0",
    "mentions": [
        {
            "id":
            "name":
        },
        {
            "id":
            "name": 
    ],
    "videoUserData": {
        "userId": 
        "name": 
        "description": 
        "views":
        "dateAdded":
        "imageLink":
    },
    "friendsAdded": [
        {
            "userId":
            "name": 
            "imageLink": 
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId":
            "name": 
            "imageLink": 
        },
        {
            "userId":,
            "name":
            "imageLink": 
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId":
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId":
            "name": 
            "imageLink": 
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink":
        },
        {
            "userId": 
            "name": 
            "imageLink": 

    ],
    "friendsDeleted": [],
    "friendsUpdated": [],
    "friendsSyncDate": "2015-05-13 17:50:34"
},
"statusCode": 200
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you would be better served using SQLite database because your JSON looks like an the structure of a database.

For faster and more convenient browsing of the data you will store, SQLite is better than SharedPreferences when you have a lot of data.

Comment: What do you mean by bean class?

Comment: bean class means ex. my Comments Array have Comment Class Which Contain all object value in data member for parsing.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use gson library to do so...
gson also provide you the JAVA Object and also you can save the json string to shared preference ..

**->for instant use ..you can use this java object**

**->otherwise use shared preference**

```
  //serialize method to set json to java object and save shared pref   
  public static <T> void serialize(Context context, Class<T> tClass, String contents, String key) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    T obj = gson.fromJson(contents, tClass);
    SharedPreferences preferencesReader = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencesReader.edit();
    editor.putString(key, gson.toJson(obj));
    editor.commit();
}

//deserialize method to get java object
 public static <T> T deserialize(Context context, Class<T> tClass, String key) {
    T obj = null;
    try {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        SharedPreferences preferencesReader = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String value = preferencesReader.getString(key, "0");
        obj = gson.fromJson(value, tClass);
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a String in Preferences, but that's not the best thing to work with .
Instead saved the `json` in a `.json` file in your `private memory` or use `SQLite` .
And access json object from the the stored place where needed.

You can basically create a util class to access it every time.